# Fill Dataset with specific data from Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I create a Datagridview named Datagrid1 and I create a Dataset named Dataset1 and create some columns in it. The data to be inserted in this Dataset is not from a database. When I click a row from Datagrid1, i store the data in a string, for example: I store "myLastname" to a variable "string lname". How can i pass the lname to Dataset1 lname column. I will use Dataset1 in my crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `DataSet` it contains one or multiple `DataTables`. You add rows to a table in this way:

```
DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables[0]; // presuming that there is already at least one
DataRow row = table.Rows.Add();
row.SetField("ColumnName", lname);
```

or

```
table.Rows.Add(lname); // if there is just one column
```

or

```
DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();  
newRow.SetField("ColumnName", lname);
table.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Comment: i have a red line in the DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables[0];

Comment: i only have one table in the dataset named Table, and its columns are: fullname, smonth, emonth, myFee, s_sec, s_no

Comment: Is it a strongly typed dataset? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb.aspx

Comment: i dont fully understand the typed dataset. i just create it and put some columns

Comment: i want to populate those fields of the dataset with data from different variables

Comment: _"i just create it"_ How have you created it? So: `var myDS = new DataSet(); ...` or via dataset-designer?

Comment: @user2650781: Then it has auto created properties and methods which names are derived from the name of the `TableAdapter` or `DataTable`. So it's difficult to help. However, since even a typed DataSet derives from a normal DataSet you should be able to use the approach above.